# How can I test for null of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, null

I can not understand the following snippet:

```
perl  -e '  
my @test = undef;  
if(@test) {print "Full\n";}'  
Full
```

It seems that `@test` although it is assigned `undef` it actually has 1 element which is `undef`.
So what is the proper way to test if `@test` is null?
Doing `if(scalar(@test) == 1 && !$test[0])` seems weird to me

Comment: You might want read my explanation here: http://perlmaven.com/undef-on-perl-arrays-and-hashes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To initialize an `@array` to nothing, just do:

```
my @test = ();
```

Currently you're doing:

```
my @test = (undef);
```

Which, as you are observing, is assigning the array a single value.

To clear an already declared array, you can use `undef` like so:

```
undef @test;
```

Comment: I thought that is how we initialize a hash

Comment: Both hashes and arrays are initialized with lists, yes.  Hashes simply expect that list to contain key/value pairs

Comment: To clear an existing array (or hash) it is best to assign an empty list to it, like so `@test = ()` and `%test = ()`. Using `undef @test` will also release the memory allocated to the array back to Perl's pool, which is usually inefficient and undesirable.